# FOR XML PATH columns - concatenate every consecutive occurrence of each value to another FOR XML PATH field

Tags: sql-server, string, concatenation, sql-server-2016, for-xml-path

Currently my result set is defined by this statement

```
 ISNULL('| ' + [Contry],'') + ISNULL('| ' + [State],'') + ISNULL('| ' + [City],'')   
 AS ProjectLocation
```

Current output of the "Place" filed shown above looks like this:

```
United States, United States, United States| California, Hawaii, Virginia| Norfolk, Pearl Harbor, San Diego,
```

I need the output look like:

```
United States,  Hawaii,  Pearl Harbor |  United States,  Virginia, Norfolk |  United States, California,  San Diego
```

The values of the columns called above are defined based of `FOR XML PATH('')` function as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        (SELECT Country.CountryName  + ', '
         FROM MyDB.dbo.Country c
         INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Contract con ON c.CountryID = con.ContryID 
                                          AND Opp.OppID = Con.OppID 
         FOR XML PATH('')) AS Country,  
        (SELECT State.StateName + ', ' 
         FROM MyDB.dbo.State s
         INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Contract con ON s.StateID = con.ContryID 
                                          AND Opp.OppID = Con.OppID 
         FOR XML PATH('')) AS State, 
        (SELECT State.StateAbbr  + ', ' 
         FROM MyDB.dbo.State s
         INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Contract con ON s.StateID = con.ContryID 
                                          AND Opp.OppID = Con.OppID 
         FOR XML PATH('')) AS StateCode, 
        (SELECT Location.LocationName  + ', ' 
         FROM MyDB.dbo.Location l
         INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Contract con ON l.LocationID= con.LocationID
                                          AND Opp.OppID = Con.OppID 
         FOR XML PATH('')) AS City
    FROM         ''"
        YourDB.dbo.Opportunity Opp
)
SELECT ...
FROM CTE
```

P.S.

The "YourDB.dbo.Opportunity" table represent a table with all projects that are available for a contractor

The "MyDB.dbo.Contract" table is a lookup table that joins project with contractors which were hired.

So that is why I need to call FOR XML Function as One Opportunity may have multiple contractors located in different states and cities.

Currently I use the very firs statement to select from the CTE as follows:

```
SELECT
  ISNULL('| ' + [Contry],'') + ISNULL('| ' + [State],'') + ISNULL('| ' + [City],'')   
 AS ProjectLocation
FROM CTE
```

But as I said it produced incorrect output.

Comment: The answer depends on how your tables are related to each other. It might be an `Addresses` table with FKs to all of them, or you may have a hierarchy among these. As such, some sample schema and data would be of great help, if you want a meaningful answer that is.

Comment: Hi Roger, per your suggestion I've added more context to the question. I hope that you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an entire address in a single table. Here is the setup I expected from you:

```
declare @Country table (Id int, Name varchar(100));
declare @State table (Id int, Name varchar(100));
declare @Location table (Id int, Name varchar(100));

declare @Opp table (
    Id int,
    CountryId int,
    StateId int,
    LocationId int,
    OpportunityDescription varchar(100)
);
```

On the schema like that, you need to join all the location tables together, combining their fields into a single output:

```
select op.*, (
    select concat(c.Name, s.Name, l.Name) as [data()]
    from @Opp p
        inner join @Country c on c.Id = p.CountryId
        inner join @State s on s.Id = p.StateId
        inner join @Location l on l.Id = p.LocationId
    where p.Id = op.Id
    for xml path('')
    ) as [OpportunityLocation]
from @Opp op;
```

Comment: Thanks Roger for your comments. I agree with your tips and suggestions. Unfortunately, this is an existing production and and the architecture is much more complex than I've represented here. I simplified it deliberately to make my question concise to serve its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine for your requirement. I would suggest you to maintain single table called Geography, instead of separate country,state, location table. 
Single geography table will make it easier to maintain. As a single city name can come under different states, countries. Eg. Bellevue city name is present in many states in USA.

```
CREATE TABLE #Opportunity(OpportunityId int)

INSERT INTO #Opportunity values(1);

CREATE TABLE #Contract(ContractID int, OpportunityID int, CountryId int, StateId int, locationId int )

INSERT INTO #Contract values(1,1,1,1,1),(2,1,1,2,2);

CREATE TABLE #Country(CountryId int, CountryName VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Country values (1,'USA');

CREATE TABLE #State(StateId int, StateName VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #State values (1,'California'),(2,'Washington');


CREATE TABLE #Location(LocationId int, LocationName VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Location values (1,'LosAngeles'),(2,'Bellevue');

SELECT c.OpportunityId, c.ContractId, STUFF( (SELECT ','+ CONCAT(CountryName,',',statename,',',locationName)
FROM #Country AS cn
left JOIN #State as s
ON c.StateId = s.StateId
left JOIN #Location AS l
ON c.LocationId = l.LocationId
WHERE c.CountryId = cn.CountryId),1,1,'')
FROM #Contract As c
```